# How to position cursor in input field after icon

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have an input field that has a search icon positioned inside of it using the background property and every time I type in it the cursor sticks in the beginning like shown in the picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9I8UN.jpg

How can I position the cursor after the search icon? I tried setting the `padding-left` and the `text-indent` but that also moves the placeholder which is not desirable.

Here is my input field:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Spinner from '../../components/Spinner/Spinner.jsx';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import axios from "axios";

class Search extends Component {

    state = {
        searchResults: [],
        isLoading: false
    }

    getSearchQuery = (event) => {
        const SEARCH_RESULTS_ENDPOINT = process.env.REACT_APP_SEARCH_ENDPOINT;

        const queryString = document.querySelector(
            ".search-input"
        ).value;
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            this.setState({ ...this.state, isLoading: true });
            axios.post(SEARCH_RESULTS_ENDPOINT, {
                queryString: queryString,

            }).then(response => {
                this.setState({ ...this.state, searchResults: response.data });
                this.setState({ ...this.state, isLoading: false });
            });
        }
    };

    render() {
        if (this.state.isLoading) {
            return <Spinner />
        }
        return (

            <div>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Search"
                    className="search-input"
                    onKeyDown={(e) => this.getSearchQuery(e)}

                />
                <div>
                    {this.state.searchResults.map(result => (
                        <div key={result._id} >
                            <img src={result.picture} alt="avatar" />
                            <div >
                                <div>
                                    <h2>{result.title}</h2>
                                    <p>{result.date}</p>
                                    <p>{result.postContent}</p>
                                    <Link to={`/post/${result._id}`} className="read-more-btn">
                                        <button className="read-more-btn">Read more</button>
                                    </Link>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ))}

                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Search;
```

and here is my CSS:

```
.search-input {
    background: url(../../assets/images/search-icon.png) no-repeat scroll 12px 12px;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    border: solid 1px #AAAAAA;
    // text-indent: 30px;
} 

.search-icon {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

.no-results-found {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 50px;
}

.search-input::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
    padding-left:35px;
}

input:focus{
  outline: none;
}

  ::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
    padding-left:20px;
}
  :-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
    padding-left:20px;
}
  :-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
    padding-left:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add some `padding` to search input as it will pad that much area.

```
.search-input {
    background: url(../../assets/images/search-icon.png) no-repeat scroll 12px 12px;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    border: solid 1px #AAAAAA;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it.

**Example with 2 variants**

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const App = () => {

return <div>
  <div className="container">
    <span className="icon">
      <i className="fas fa-search"></i>   
    </span>
    <input className="input" type="Text" placeholder="Search"/>
  </div>
  <div className="container1">
    <span className="icon1">
      <i className="fas fa-search"></i>   
    </span>
    <input className="input1" type="Text" placeholder="Search"/>
  </div>
</div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
}

.input {
  padding: .5rem .5rem .5rem 2rem;
  border: none;
}

.input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: .5rem;
  margin-left: .5rem;
}




.container1 {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
}

.icon1 {
  padding: .5rem 0 .5rem .5rem;
}

.input1 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: .5rem;
  border: none;
}

.input1:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0-2/js/all.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```